# Laravel-mix with browserSync, and tailwindCss causes infinite reloading bug

Tags: tailwind-css, laravel-mix

In my latest project, I'm using laravel-mix with the built in browserSync, and I've added tailwindCss as a package.

This is the `webpack.mix.js` file:

```js
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
require('mix-html-builder');

mix
    .setResourceRoot("../")
    .setPublicPath("public/assets")
    .browserSync({
        proxy: 'xxx',
        host: 'xxx',
        files: "public/*",
        open: false,
        reloadOnRestart: true
    })
    .html({
        htmlRoot: './resources/html/pages/*.html',
        partialRoot: './resources/html/components',
        output: '..'
    })
    .copy("resources/images", "public/assets/images")
    .js("resources/js/app.js", "js")
    .postCss(
        "resources/css/app.css",
        "css",
        [
            require("postcss-import"),
            require("tailwindcss/nesting"),
            require("tailwindcss"),
            require("autoprefixer")
        ]
    )
```

As soon as I comment out either the line `require("tailwindcss")`, or the `.html({})` block, the watch command `npm run watch` runs nicely, if both of them are on, the mix command will run indefinitely in an endless loop (in the terminal). There are no errors, everyhting runs, it just won't stop running anymore :D

My `package.json` is as follows:

```js
{
    "name": "xxx",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "## Deployment",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "xxx"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.11.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.11.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.8.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "eslint": "^8.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
        "filename-regex": "^2.0.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.41",
        "mix-html-builder": "^0.8.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
        "stylelint": "^14.4.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^25.0.0",
        "stylelint-order": "^5.0.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.19"
    }
}
```

I think I'm probably missing a simple setting somewhere, can someone point me to where this might go wrong?

---

### The solution to this particular case:

This is my **new** `tailwind.config.js` file, after @reid-gannah posted their answer. At first my content config pointed to the end of the pipeline, due to how the project was set up initially, initiating the infinite lading bug. After changing filestructure around (and implementing `mix-html-builder`), I never realised Tailwind still read from the generated files instead of source. So, the config below solves my question:

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: "jit",
    content: [
        './resources/html/pages/**/*.{html,js}',
        './resources/html/components/**/*.{html,js}',
        './resources/html/layouts/**/*.{html,js}',
    ],
    theme: {
        container: {
        },
        extend: {}
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {}
    },
};
```

Comment: Wow, I've never found a question this fresh before. I'm experiencing/troubleshooting this exact same issue. What does your tailwing.config.js file look like? The only thing I've discovered is that messing with the `content` paths/glob patterns seem to affect it. I can have tailwind "watch" *.php files in subdirectories, but none in the same directory as the actual tailwind.config.js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I think I discovered what's going on here. Looks like it's a known issue with Webpack documented by Tailwind themselves:

> If your CSS seems to be rebuilding in an infinite loop, there’s a good chance it’s because your build tool doesn’t support the glob option when registering PostCSS dependencies.
> Many build tools (such as webpack) don’t support this option, and as a result we can only tell them to watch specific files or entire directories. We can’t tell webpack to only watch *.html files in a directory for example.
> That means that if building your CSS causes any files in those directories to change, a rebuild will be triggered, even if the changed file doesn’t match the extension in your glob.

And here's their recommendation:

> To solve this problem, use more specific paths in your content config, making sure to only include directories that won’t change when your CSS builds:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{html,js}',
    './src/pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './src/components/**/*.{html,js}',
    './src/layouts/**/*.{html,js}',
    './src/index.html',
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Kind of a bummer, hopefully this helps.

Source: [Tailwind CSS: Content Configuration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#styles-rebuild-in-an-infinite-loop)

Comment: That's great! It wasn't a glob for me, but I did point to the incorrect paths in content config, so your solution did definitely save my day. The generated Tailwind css files kept on triggering the watch. I hadn't figured out it was Tailwind specificly, great find in the docs! I even had the documentation open at the time...

Comment: @Kablam that's great! So is it working as expected in your build then? Would you mind sharing your tailwind.config.js if so? Curious if you're having to target specific directories/files or if you're able to have it scan more broadly. In my setup, I still get an infinite loop if I have any patterns with a globstar `**` in `content`. I might have an issue elsewhere though...

Comment: I'm still using globs, the problem for me was that the `content: ` pointed to generated files. After specifying the source files the infinite loop didn't occur anymore. I'll add my tailwind.config to the question. If you start a question of your own, or have another place to post your code, I'll gladly look along to see if we can figure it out together!

Comment: Thanks yeah looking at your edit, it confirms that I also need to restructure my folders/assets a bit. Kind of annoying for me because it's a custom WP theme and doesn't play nice with moving core files around, but I think I'll be able to figure it out. Just weird because I've found other tutorials out there using the same build (Webpack + Tailwind + Wordpress) and they seem to be able to have Tailwind scan more broadly... oh well.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a potentially lengthy Google session.